# "Ambiguous associated type" when returning a generic lambda

Tags: generics, lambda, rust

I have this code (contrived and purely experimental)

```
fn math_op(op: &str) -> Option<Box<Fn(i32, i32) -> i32>> {
    let ret: Option<Box<Fn(i32, i32) -> i32>> = match op {
        "+" => Some(Box::new(|a: i32, b: i32| -> i32 { a + b } )),
        "-" => Some(Box::new(|a: i32, b: i32| -> i32 { a - b } )),
        "*" => Some(Box::new(|a: i32, b: i32| -> i32 { a * b } )),
        "/" => Some(Box::new(|a: i32, b: i32| -> i32 { a / b } )),
        _ => None,
    };

    ret
}
```

It returns a function/lambda that takes two operands and returns a result (in this case the addition, subtraction, divide and multiply operators)

Which can be called like so:

```
let add: Option<Box<Fn(i32, i32) -> i32>> = math_op("+");
println!("Add {}", add.unwrap()(10, 2));
```

I would really like to make a generic version of this, so far I have...

```
fn math_op_gen<T>(op: &str) -> Option<Box<Fn(T, T) -> T::Output>> 
    where T: std::ops::Add + std::ops::Sub + std::ops::Mul + std::ops::Div {
        let ret: Option<Box<Fn(T, T) -> T::Output>> = match op {
            "+" => Some(Box::new(|a, b| { a + b } )),
            "-" => Some(Box::new(|a, b| { a - b } )),
            "*" => Some(Box::new(|a, b| { a * b } )),
            "/" => Some(Box::new(|a, b| { a / b } )),
            _ => None,
        };

        ret
}
```

But when I build I get these errors:

```
error: ambiguous associated type `Output` in bounds of `T` [E0221]
note: associated type `T` could derive from `core::ops::Div`
note: associated type `T` could derive from `core::ops::Mul`
note: associated type `T` could derive from `core::ops::Sub`
note: associated type `T` could derive from `core::ops::Add`
```

I understand this is because the compiler cannot determine what type T::Output is from the various traits I have implemented. Is there another way of writing this to get it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the output types of `Add`, `Sub`, `Mul` and `Div` to be the same. You can enforce this by adding another type parameter and constraining each trait's `Output` to be this type parameter.

```
fn math_op_gen<T, R>(op: &str) -> Option<Box<Fn(T, T) -> R>> 
    where T: std::ops::Add<Output=R> +
             std::ops::Sub<Output=R> +
             std::ops::Mul<Output=R> +
             std::ops::Div<Output=R> {
        let ret: Option<Box<Fn(T, T) -> R>> = match op {
            "+" => Some(Box::new(|a, b| { a + b } )),
            "-" => Some(Box::new(|a, b| { a - b } )),
            "*" => Some(Box::new(|a, b| { a * b } )),
            "/" => Some(Box::new(|a, b| { a / b } )),
            _ => None,
        };

        ret
}
```